# The entire scrollbar moves in a CWnd when calling ScrollWindowEx with SW_SCROLLCHILDREN

Tags: c++, mfc

I've added a CScrollBar to my Cwnd named CPanel. But when I scroll the page the whole scrollbar moves. Any idea how I can solve this? Changing CPanel to a CScrollView or CFormView is sadly not an option.

```
CPanel::CPanel()
{
    CreateEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, _T("Static"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER, m_clRect, pwndParent, IDC_PANEL_FORM);
    ScrollBarInit();    
}

void CPanel::ScrollBarInit()
{

    //Before this i calculate size of scrollbar and size of scrollarea
    m_pclScrollBar = new CScrollBar();
    m_pclScrollBar->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT | SBS_RIGHTALIGN, clRectScrollbar, this, IDC_SCROLLBAR_FORM);
    m_pclScrollBar->SetScrollRange(VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN, VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX);
    //After this I add scrollbar info

}

void CPanel::OnVScroll(UINT iSBCode, UINT iPos, CScrollBar* pclScrollBar)
{
    switch(pclScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID())
    {
        case IDC_SCROLLBAR_FORM:
            ScrollBarScroll(iSBCode, iPos, pclScrollBar);
            break;
    }
}

void CPanel::ScrollBarScroll(UINT iSBCode, UINT iPos, CScrollBar *pclScrollBar)
{
    int     iScrollPositionPrevious;
    int     iScrollPosition;
    int     iScrollPositionOriginal;

    iScrollPositionOriginal = m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollPos();
    iScrollPosition = iScrollPositionOriginal;

    if(m_pclScrollBar != NULL)
    {
        SCROLLINFO info = {sizeof( SCROLLINFO ), SIF_ALL};
        pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&info, SB_CTL);

        pclScrollBar->GetScrollRange(&info.nMin, &info.nMax);
        info.nPos = pclScrollBar->GetScrollPos();

        iScrollPositionPrevious = info.nPos;

        switch(iSBCode)
        {
            case SB_TOP:            // Scroll to top
                iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN;
                break;

            case SB_BOTTOM:         // Scroll to bottom
                iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX;
                break;

            case SB_ENDSCROLL:      // End scroll
                break;

            case SB_LINEUP:         // Scroll one line up
                if(iScrollPosition - VSCROLL_LINE >= VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN)
                    iScrollPosition -= VSCROLL_LINE;
                else
                    iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN;
                break;

            case SB_LINEDOWN:       // Scroll one line down
                if(iScrollPosition + VSCROLL_LINE <= VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX)
                    iScrollPosition += VSCROLL_LINE;
                else
                    iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX;
                break;

            case SB_PAGEUP:         // Scroll one page up
            {
                // Get the page size
                SCROLLINFO   scrollInfo;
                m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&scrollInfo, SIF_ALL);

                if(iScrollPosition > VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN)
                    iScrollPosition = max(VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN, iScrollPosition - VSCROLL_PAGE);
                break;
            }

            case SB_PAGEDOWN:       // Scroll one page down
            {
                // Get the page size
                SCROLLINFO   scrollInfo;
                m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&scrollInfo, SIF_ALL);

                if(iScrollPosition < VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX)
                    iScrollPosition = min(VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX, iScrollPosition + VSCROLL_PAGE);
                break;
            }

            case SB_THUMBPOSITION:  // Scroll to the absolute position. The current position is provided in nPos
            case SB_THUMBTRACK:     // Drag scroll box to specified position. The current position is provided in nPos
                iScrollPosition = iPos;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if(iScrollPositionOriginal != iScrollPosition)
        {
            m_pclScrollBar->SetScrollPos(iScrollPosition);

            ScrollWindowEx(0, iScrollPositionOriginal - iScrollPosition, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `ScrollWindowEx` is creating problem.  If you are scrolling the window, just `SetScrollPos` should be fine and all other drawing should respect the scroll position.

Comment: @Kiran Not sure if I understand what you mean. If i remove ScrollWindowEx and just use SetScrollPos nothing happens, except for that the handle in the scrollbar moves (or stays where you left it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified `SW_SCROLLCHILDREN` in your call to [ScrollWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwbfte93.aspx) (see also the Windows API documentation for [ScrollWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787593.aspx); it is usually better than MFC's), and requested the entire client area to be scrolled by passing `NULL` for the *lpRectScroll* parameter, the system does just that. The scrollbar is a child window as well, so it gets moved like all other child controls.

The solution is hinted to in the documentation for [SW_SCROLLCHILDREN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwbfte93.aspx):

> Scrolls all child windows that intersect the rectangle pointed to by *lpRectScroll* by the number of pixels specified in dx and dy.

To prevent the scrollbar from moving alongside the other child windows, it must be excluded from the rectangle passed as the *lpRectScroll* parameter. To do so, query the client area, and subtract the area occupied by the scrollbar. Assuming that the scrollbar is at the right and covers the entire height, the following code will solve your issue:

```
if(iScrollPositionOriginal != iScrollPosition) {
    m_pclScrollBar->SetScrollPos(iScrollPosition);

    // Query the window's client area
    CRect clientArea;
    GetClientRect(clientArea);
    // Find the area occupied by the scrollbar
    CRect scrollbarArea;
    m_pclScrollBar->GetWindowRect(scrollbarArea);
    // Adjust the client area to exclude the scrollbar area
    CRect scrollArea(clientArea);
    scrollArea.DeflateRect(0, 0, scrollbarArea.Width(), 0);
    ScrollWindowEx(0, iScrollPositionOriginal - iScrollPosition, scrollArea, NULL,
                   NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE);
}
```

Also keep in mind the remark on using the `SW_SCROLLCHILDREN` flag:

> If the [SW_SCROLLCHILDREN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb787593) flag is specified, Windows will not properly update the screen if part of a child window is scrolled. The part of the scrolled child window that lies outside the source rectangle will not be erased and will not be redrawn properly in its new destination. Use the [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632681) Windows function to move child windows that do not lie completely within the *lpRectScroll* rectangle.

Since you don't have control over the amount of pixels the user will scroll, there will be situations where the screen will not properly update. To work around this, implement a solution following the procedure outlined in the quote above: Replace the call to `ScrollWindowEx` with a series of calls to `DeferWindowPos`, repositioning all child windows manually.

Comment: I've implemented your code and it works. However I have the update problem that you're talking about. When I've scrolled down and up again the window is empty.

Comment: @JohanMagnusson: `ScrollWindowEx` is fairly low-level, and was initially implemented as a pure block transfer of pixels. It doesn't know or care about higher-level constructs, like controls. The `SW_SCROLLCHILDREN` flag was added as a utility, and fails to compensate for all possible scenarios. It works, as long as all child windows remain completely visible in the process of scrolling. The issue of scrolling controls that are partially clipped is a new problem, and you should ask a new question. While related in your specific case, this may not be the case for others.

Comment: Yes of course. I really appreciate the help! However i'm stuck at the DeferWindowPos part. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154470/controls-disappear-after-scrolling-in-cwnd-with-scrollwindowex